# Compare stringified numerical value lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have the below lists examples. I want to get the following expected outputs.

```
example1:
    
list_for_compare = ['1', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10']
mainlist = ['4', '7', '9']

expected_output1 = [["4", "5"], ["7", "8"], ["9", "10"]]

example2:
    
list_for_compare = ['1.2.1', '1.2.3', '2.2.5', '3.2.4', '5.4.3', '5.5.1', '5.8.2']
mainlist = ['1.2.2', '2.2.4', '5.4.2']

expected_output2 = [["1.2.2", "1.2.3"], ["2.2.4", "2.2.5", "3.2.4"], ["5.4.2", "5.4.3", "5.5.1", "5.8.2"]]
```

I tried below code to find inbetween items.

```
def inbetweenitems_list(mainlist, inbetween):
    withmidlist = []
    for i in range(len(mainlist)-1):
        found = filter(lambda x: mainlist[i] <= x <= mainlist[i+1], inbetween)
        withmidlist.append([mainlist[i] , list(found) , mainlist[i+1]])
    return withmidlist
```

The output is as below:

```
example1:
    
inbetweenitems_list(mainlist, list_for_compare) 

output1 = [['4', ['4', '5', '7'], '7'], ['7', ['7', '8', '9'], '9']]

example2:
    
inbetweenitems_list(mainlist, list_for_compare)

output2 = [['1.2.2', ['1.2.3'], '2.2.4'], ['2.2.4', ['2.2.5', '3.2.4'], '5.4.2']]
```

I'm not finding many ways to filter and compare stringified numbers and get the expected outputs.

Comment: I do not understand the pattern. How exactly do you form these pairs in expected results?

Comment: For every main list i , i+1 items, check the list_for_compare for in between items and appended i item in mainlist with items from list_for_compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract all numbers from the strings and convert them to integers in a tuple.  This will make them comparable using their numeric content.

```
import re
def sortedSplit(L,splits,key=None):
    if not key: # convert string to comparable tuple of numbers
        key = lambda v:tuple(map(int,re.findall(r"\d+",v)))  
    result = [[s] for s in splits]         # split value is first of group
    for v in L:                            # process values
        for r in reversed(result):         # find group to place value in
            if key(v)<key(r[0]):continue   # skip larger split values
            if v != r[0] : r.append(v)     # add to group
            break                          # group found, process next value
    return result
```

Output:

```
L = ['1', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10']
S = ['4', '7', '9']
print(sortedSplit(L,S))
# [['4', '5', '7'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['9', '10']]

L = ['1.2.1', '1.2.3', '2.2.5', '3.2.4', '5.4.3', '5.5.1', '5.8.2']
S = ['1.2.2', '2.2.4', '5.4.2']
print(sortedSplit(L,S))
# [['1.2.2', '1.2.3'], ['2.2.4', '2.2.5', '3.2.4'], 
   ['5.4.2', '5.4.3', '5.5.1', '5.8.2']]
```

To make it run slightly faster, you can use a binary search function to find the target group for each value. The `bisect` module has a `bisect_right` function that performs a binary search in an ordered list and returns an index.

```
import re
from bisect import bisect_right
def sortedSplit(L,splits,key=None):
    if not key: # convert string to comparable tuple of numbers
        key = lambda v:tuple(map(int,re.findall(r"\d+",v)))  
    result    = [[s] for s in splits]        # split value is first of group
    splitKeys = list(map(key,splits))        # sorted keys in for binary search
    for v in L:                              # process values
        g = bisect_right(splitKeys,key(v))-1 # find target group for value
        if g>=0 and splits[g] != v:          # add if not = split value
            result[g].append(v)
    return result
```

Comment: Great !! This works well

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask.  This also makes an entry for all the items prior to the first match; you can remove the top entry in the output list, if you want.

```
def process(list_for_compare, mainlist):
    output = []
    accum = []
    nextup = mainlist.pop(0)
    for item in list_for_compare:
        if item >= nextup:
            output.append(accum)
            accum = []
            nextup = mainlist.pop(0) if mainlist else 'zzzz'
        accum.append( item )
    output.append(accum)
    return output

print(process( ['1', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10'], ['4', '7', '9'] ) )
print(process( ['1.2.1', '1.2.3', '2.2.5', '3.2.4', '5.4.3', '5.5.1', '5.8.2'], ['1.2.2', '2.2.4', '5.4.2'] )
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py
[['1'], ['4', '5'], ['7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
[['1.2.1'], ['1.2.3'], ['2.2.5', '3.2.4'], ['5.4.3', '5.5.1', '5.8.2']]
```